# Lagrangian of KS system under gauge field

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, density-functional-theory

Do you know how to derive this Lagrangian quantity?

[image]

It came from:

> Bertsch, G. F., Iwata, J.-I., Rubio, A. & Yabana, K. Real-space, real-time method for the dielectric function. Phys Rev B 62, 7998–8002 (2000).

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.